# Angular2 - Set A Different Color to an element Depending On Value

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am new to `Angular2` and was wondering how I go about setting a font color to an element depending on the value.

My scenario is: if the value of the input field is not 100 then I want it red but if it is 100 then I want it green.

I have the following code in place but cant get it working.

**XXX.component.css**

```
.red {
    color: red; 
}

.green {
    color: green;
}
```

**XXX.component.css**

```
<input mdInput placeholder="Proportion '%'" [(ngModel)]="proportion ">
<p>hello <span ng-class='{red : proportion!= '100', green: proportion === '100'}'>{{proportion}}</span></p>
```

Comment: use `proportion` here `g-class='{red : username != '100', green: username === '100'}` instead of `username`, let me know if it works

Comment: Sorry copy and paste error, already changed it to 'proportion'

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two solutions to change font color but depends on you requirement

1. If you requirement is change inline style then you can use angular `NgStyle` Directive which Update an HTML element styles for you..

`NgStyle directive Ex:`

```
<span [ngStyle]="{'color': proportion === '100' ? 'green' : 'red'}"></span>

        ---------------------- OR -----------------------------------

<span [style.color]="proportion === '100' ? 'green' : 'red'"></span>
```

2. If you requirement is change class then you can use angular `NgClass` Directive which Adds and removes CSS classes on an HTML element...

`NgClass directive Ex:`

```
<span [ngClass]="{proportion === '100' ? 'green': 'red'}"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also bind the style property.

```
<span [style.color]="proportion === '100' ? 'green' : 'red'"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this:

```
 <div class="card template-card" [ngClass]="{'z-depth-3': template == selectedTemplate, 'not-selected': !(template == selectedTemplate) && selectedTemplate != null}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `Angular2`, So you need to use `[ngClass]`, and your input model is bind to `proportion`, So use it to compare,

Do it like :

```
<input mdInput placeholder="Proportion '%'" [(ngModel)]="proportion">
<p>hello <span [ngClass]="{'red': proportion !== '100', 'green': proportion === '100'}">{{username}}</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your logic to have double quotes and ngModel **proportion** value

```
<input mdInput placeholder="Proportion '%'" [(ngModel)]="proportion">
<p>hello <span [ngClass]="{red : proportion != '100', green: proportion === '100'}">{{username}}</span></p>
```

Hope it helps!!