# Can i write a CSS class under conditional [ngCLASS]

Tags: jquery, css, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I do have some problem with writing the logic.
i am using Angular2.
In html Page,i have two button- YES and NO
I want different colors for YES and NO.
So in the div tag, i have the condition like this:

```
ngClass="'result'?'yes':'no'"
```

Now how i use CSS classes. I have the class *green-button* for YES and *red-button* for NO.
How to use them in [ngClass].

Comment: It contains yes and no value from API.

Comment: I am showing the TEXT in a button.My query is to change the color w.r.t yes and no.

Comment: If Answer is Yes then green color button or red color button.

Comment: if `result = 'yes'` ==> add class yes. If `result = 'no'` ==> add class no. Right?

Comment: yes @Duannx Ri8

Comment: Just simply `[ngClass]="result"`

Comment: You don't understand. result contains the values:YES and NO.I have to show on the buttons. That i had done .Now i want to change the button color with respect to YES and NO. So my css classes are .red-button and .green-button. How to give these classes with respect to YES and NO.??

Comment: check here you might get a solution you are searching for https://stackoverflow.com/a/44429236/5868331

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<div class=" form-group" [ngClass]="{ (result==='YES')? 'green-button': 'red-button'}">
```

Hope it helps..:)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply different classes based on different conditions you can do following

```
<div class=" form-group" [ngClass]="{'green-button': green-button-condition, 'red-button': red-button-condition}">
```

Replace `green-button-condition` and `red-button-condition` with your conditions

Comment: This is right @umar But i have the condition in the ' '?' ' : ' ' like this.

Comment: [ngClass]="'result'?'yes':'no'"
This line should be present . Now update this.Any idea.

Comment: You need to rephrase your condition to angular way

Comment: [ngClass]="{'green-button': result=='yes', 'red-button': result=='no'}"