# How to assign different colour to mat-row in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

The case here is I want to assign colour to each row of mat table based on some logic (for e.g orderId of the list) for `orderId <= 1000` colour should be red, for `1000 < orderId  <= 2000`, colour should be green and `orderId > 2000`, colour should be yellow. I tried this but unable to achieve the desired output:

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" 
         (click)="highlightedRows.push(row)" 
         [style.background]="highlightedRows.indexOf(row) != -1 ? backgroundColor : ''">
</mat-row>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: provide a stackblitz demo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44429236/5868331

Answer (score 1):

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index"         
         [style.background]="getBackgroundColour(i)">
</mat-row>
```

```
getBackgroundColour(i) {
    if(i <= 1000) {
        return 'red'
    }
    if(i <= 2000) {
        return 'green'
    }
    if(i > 2000) {
        return 'yellow'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call a function in html

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" (click)="highlightedRows.push(row)" [style.background]="setBgColor(row.orderId)"></mat-row>
```

and in your ts you can add a function

```
  setBgColor(orderId: number){
    if(orderId <= 1000){
      return "#ff0000";
    }
    else if(orderId  <= 2000 && orderId > 1000){
      return "#008000";
    }
    return "#ffff00";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngClass for this. This will require to make css classes with the required color.

Then after this you need to do:

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" (click)="highlightedRows.push(row)" 
[ngClass]="{'redClass': row.orderId <= 1000, 'greenClass': row.orderId > 1000 && row.orderId <= 2000, 'yellowClass': row.orderId > 2000}">
```

Source: [Multiple conditions in ngClass - Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821875/multiple-conditions-in-ngclass-angular-4)